# Issue with PHP Loop Record not Inserting

Tags: php

I am trying to insert records into mysql database tables using Simple HTML DOM.

Checkout the codes..

```
<?php
$startpage=1;
$endpage=2;
for($p=$startpage;$p<=$endpage;$p++)
{
    $html = file_get_html("http://examplesite.com/index.php?page=$p");

    // connect to main page links
    foreach($html->find('div.tt-name a[1]') as $link)
    {   
        $linkHref = $link->href;
        $url[] = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($linkHref));        

        //loop through each link
        $linkHtml = file_get_html('http://examplesite.com'.$linkHref);

        $title=array();
        $size=array();

        foreach($linkHtml->find('div#content h1') as $title2) 
        {
            $title[] = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($tit2));
        }

        foreach($linkHtml->find('div.torrentinfo table tr[3]') as $size2) 
        {               
            $size[] = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($size2));          
        }

        $qv = $conn->query("INSERT INTO data (title, size, url) VALUES('$title[$i]', '$size[$i]', '$url[$i]')");
        if($qv){print "<br>Record Inserted..!!";}
        else {print "<br>".$conn->error;}
        $i++;

    }
}       

?>
```

Everything is working fine only problem with `$url[]` on line 11 its not inserting all records, its only inserting first record.
I guess its not inside the loop, how to fix this?

Comment: `$i=+1;` should be `$i+=1;` or `$i++;`

Comment: @Popnoodles i have updated my codes but still the same problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed it, this line

```
$url[] = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($linkHref));
```

needed to move down near to sql query only.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `$i=0` out of the for loop and fix incrementing of x to `$i++`